# Edge is unable to set clipboardData

Tags: javascript, dom, clipboard, microsoft-edge

First of all, let me note that this works perfectly in Chrome.

I am trying to override the copy event in JavaScript and replace the clipboard contents with my own data. I extracted the essentials of the problem into this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gxewmc2h/4/ (yes, I need to use global variables to set the data)

```
window.globalCopyObject = {};
window.globalCopyObject.clipboardDataText = "text value";
window.globalCopyObject.clipboardHtmlText = "html value";

document.addEventListener("copy", function (event) {        
    event.clipboardData.setData("text/plain", window.globalCopyObject.clipboardDataText);
    event.clipboardData.setData("text/html", window.globalCopyObject.clipboardHtmlText);
    event.preventDefault();        
});
```

When you use Edge and try to copy the text on the page and paste it into the input, it does override the event since the clipboard is emptied, but it does not fill it with new data.

As far as I know, the latest Edge should support the clipboard API, is there something obvious I am missing?

Thank you in advance for any ideas.